# Is there a concrete proof showing that hinge loss is an upper bound on the 0-1 loss?

Tags: statistical-inference, machine-learning

While it is stated in several places that the Hinge loss is a convex upper bound on the 0-1 loss, is there a proof behind it? From what I have seen, most resources just show the plots of hinge loss and 0-1 loss and mention that its a convex upper bound on the 0-1 loss. For y>-1 and a small value of y_pred, wont the hinge loss be smaller than 0-1?

[Plot of Hinge loss and 0-1 loss](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LsVxe.png)

Answer (score 0):

There are several functions called the "hinge loss" and depending on which one you pick, the answer may vary... but from your graph it looks like you're considering $h(x)=\max\{0,1-x\}$. If this is the case, then yes, it is larger than $1_{\mathbb{R}_-}$

Proof:  for any $x\in\mathbb{R}$

\begin{aligned}
h(x)&=
\begin{cases}
1-x &\text{if } x\leq 1\\
0 &\text{if } 1<x
\end{cases}\\
&=
\begin{cases}
1-x &\text{if } x<0\\
1-x &\text{if } 0\leq x\leq 1\\
0 &\text{if }  1 < x
\end{cases}\\
&\geq 
\begin{cases}
1 &\text{if } x<0\\
0 &\text{if } 0\leq x\leq 1\\
0 &\text{if }  1 < x
\end{cases}\\
&=1_{\mathbb{R}_-}
\end{aligned}

Comment: Thanks! Then in case of a correctly classified example, does the hinge loss lie in [0,1] i.e., its still bounded?

Comment: @IllustriousImp Nope, the hinge loss is an unbounded function. e.g. with $h$ above, this is seen as $x\to-\infty$

Comment: Sorry...my bad...I meant for a correctly classified example

Comment: No worries. In that case, I'm not sure I understand your follow-up question